# Welche Art Nebensatz ist der Teil nach dem Komma in "Ich glaube, das verstehen die schon"?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Ich glaube, **das verstehen die schon**.

Welche Art Nebensatz ist der Teil nach dem Komma?

Ich kann ihn leider nicht einordnen. Möglicherweise ist er auch grammatikalisch nicht korrekt.
"Ich glaube, dass die das schon verstehen" ist vielleicht die korrekte Version des Satzes.

Comment: Ich habe hier eine ähnliche Frage gefunden. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71949/can-dass-be-omitted-in-subclause
Jetzt, wo ich genauer hinschaue, ist der zweite Satz ein Hauptsatz. Es sind also zwei Hauptsätze mit einem Komma voneinander getrennt. Aber unter welchen Umständen man zwei Hauptsätze mit einem Komma trennen darf, weiß ich noch nicht.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "dass" be omitted in subclause?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71949/can-dass-be-omitted-in-subclause)

Comment: @Benice Das ist falsch, siehe meine Antwort, Dass es keine zwei Hauptsätze sind, kann man daran sehen, dass sich die Bedeutung ändert, wenn die Sätze als Hauptsätze gelesen werden, etwa wenn sie durch Punkt statt durch Komma getrennt werden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Frage sollte lauten, welche Art Nebensatz der Teil nach dem Komma ist, denn der Satz als Ganzes ist ein Hauptsatz.

"die verstehen das schon" ist ein *Objektsatz*, genauer ein uneingeleiteter Objektsatz, weil er nicht durch eine Konjunktion eingeleitet wird. Objektsatz deshalb, weil der Nebensatz als Ganzes Objekt des Verbs *glauben* ist.

"dass die das schon verstehen" ist demgegenüber ein *eingeleiteter* Objektsatz, der durch die Konjunktion *dass* eingeleitet wird.